# algorithm diagonal fade jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, fade, slide

I'm trying to create a diagonal fade effect with content like on this image :

[image: Grid]

So the idea is to have the first fade and after the others with a delay. ( Using Javascript / jQuery I guess)

I have no preferences about the method used if it's a list, div, whatever.A library doing it or something.

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider/blob/master/jquery.nivo.slider.js#L532

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery and javascript to accomplish this. Separate into rows and label each row as the same class "one", "two", "three".  Then fade in each of these.  This is a rough example but will work if you tweak it.

```
<script>
$(document).(ready(function(){
 $(".one").each(function(){
   $(this).fadeIn();
 });

 $(".two").each(function(){
   $(this).fadeIn();
 });

 $(".three").each(function(){
   $(this).fadeIn();
 });
});
</script>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row-one-wrapper">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">4</div>
  <div class="four">7</div>
  <div class="five">9</div>
  <div class="six">11</div>
</div>

<div class="row-two-wrapper">
  <div class="two">3</div>
  <div class="three">5</div>
  <div class="four">8</div>
  <div class="five">12</div>
  <div class="six">17</div>
</div>
</div>
```